# Is I am outside correct sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, american-english

Consider the situation when someone is calling you, and you are in a busy street. Is sending a message - I am outside correct English? 
Although it does convey the meaning that I am not at home.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to say 'I am out'. (Out- away from home etc.)

I am out. (I am not at home.)

'I am outside' means I am not inside the building. 'Outside' means 'not in a building (but near it)'

I am outside (of) London. (somewhere else but not in London)

'Out' can be used in place of 'outside'.

Comment: If I say - I am out. Does it also convey that I cannot talk right now?

Answer (score 0):

"I am outside" is not wrong altough it doesn't give any specific information where you are. It only says you are not home or under a roof in general.

Comment: _Out of doors_ would be better. _Outside_ is usually associated with having stepped out of a particular building - "I'm at home, but I'm outside in the garden."